# Paste not working on scheduled task

Tags: powershell, task, export-to-excel, scheduler

I have a script that gather some data and copy that data to excel.
The script works fine when logged in.

As a scheduled task, I get the following error :

```
   Exception calling "Paste" with "0" argument(s): "Paste method of Worksheet
class failed"
At E:\scripts\powercli_datastore_usage.ps1:193 char:5
+     $sheet.Paste()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

The thing is :

- I am able to add some sheets to my workbook. (so the Excel ComObject is loaded correctly).
- I can write my content to a text file, there is some content.

I had to do some configuration but make excel work on a scheduled task.

Is there something special to do to allow a scheduled task to access the "Paste" function ?

```
Add-Array2Clipboard $array -Header:$True
$selection = $sheet.Range("A1")
$selection.Select() | Out-Null
$sheet.Paste()
```

As an interactive user, all run fine.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you are actually copying anything. Do the following with your code to copy:

```
$selection.Copy();
```

The way you have it now will only copy the single cell. To copy an entire column, you can do the following:

```
$selection.EntireColumn.Copy();
```

Hope this helps.